# Kubuntu panel clock display in 12-hour format but without AM/PM?

Tags: kubuntu, panel, clock

I have the Kubuntu panel positioned vertically and that doesn't leave a lot of room for horizontal text strings. The clock is in 12-hour format, and the AM/PM text after the HH:MM makes the text string too long.
How can I get 12-hour format, without the AM/PM text?

Comment: I don't see any obvious option for the user to get rid of AM/PM in 12-h mode. It *may* be possible to edit some system files to get what you want. It maybe simpler to shorten your panel's height and stick in a small conky to provide you with the time format you need. Conky uses the format laid down in `man strftime` so `${time %I}:${time %M}` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to remove `AM/PM` from Kubuntu's digital clock if the time display is set to "12-Hour" and don't see any such options. If it's possible, it would probably involve knowledge of programming `qt` applications.

However, it is possible to use [Conky](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/conky.1.html) to display 12-Hour times without `AM/PM`. Conky uses the format specified by [man strftime](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man3/strftime.3.html). In other words, `date +%I:%M` will output `06:05` when the current time is `18:05`.

I used Conky with the conky.conf below to add 12-Hour times without `AM/PM` just below Kubuntu's panel so that both Kubuntu's digital clock displaying 24-Hour time and Conky's window showing 12-Hour time (without AM/PM) are visible:

### Both 24-Hour and 12-Hour formats visible

[image: Kubuntu panel + Conky]

To do this, I reduced the length of the vertical panel so that some space is available in the left lower corner of the screen.

I installed *conky* with `sudo apt install conky-all` and created `12h-conky.conf` with the following content in `~/.config/conky`.

```
conky.config = {
    update_interval = 1,
    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'conky',
    own_window_colour = '050505',
    own_window_transparent = yes,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 5,
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
    own_window_type = 'dock',
    background = false,
    gap_y = 0,
    gap_x = 1,
    alignment = 'bottom_left',
    draw_shades = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    use_xft = true, --needed to show font correctly
    uppercase = true
}

conky.text = [[
${font Noto:size=13}${color cccccc}${time %I}:${time %M}
]]
```

Notes:

1. `update_interval = 1,` should be changed to `update_interval = 30,` or more once the tweaking (of font, font size, font color, background color and transparency, etc) is done.
2. This Conky can be run on demand using `conky -c $HOME/.config/conky/12h-conky.conf & exit` or  it can be added to one's autostart.

---

Another route is to use `latte dock`. It displays an analogue clock (by default) which fits decently in the dock when oriented vertically. If need be, the conky can still be used but I changed `bottom_left` to `bottom_right`.

[image: Latte dock with analogue clock plus conky]

*Latte Dock* is very configurable. I have version 0.9.7 because I use the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) in Kubuntu 19.10:

```
lattedock 0.9.7
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.65.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-24-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```